# Microsoft graph API: getting 5 next instances of recurring meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

is there a way to query for next 5 instances of given series? I am querying using time-frame:
1. ask for all the meetings for next 7 days for all user events
2. Go over each event fetched and check if event has masterSerieId
3. Return matching instances.

This feels (and is) a bit painful.

Can i request next X instances of master series right away? I can't just simply or 'simply' get them based on recurrence rule, as some might have expired.

I could image I could ask for a year ahead and pass as a query parameter masterSeriesId and limit output with $top. Is that right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#GetEventInstances), you could call /events//instances – given a start time, returns all instances in the requested time frame of the meeting specified by the provided series master ID